# JQuery toFixed() not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a set of numbers such as this:

```
<select name="amount" id="amount" class="form-control">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Donation Amount</option>
        <option value="500">$5.00</option>
        <option value="1000">$10.00</option>
        <option value="1500">$15.00</option>
        <option value="2000">$20.00</option>
        <option value="2500">$25.00</option>
        <option value="3000">$30.00</option>
        <option value="3500">$35.00</option>
        <option value="4000">$40.00</option>
        <option value="4500">$45.00</option>
        <option value="5000">$50.00</option>
        <option value="5500">$55.00</option>
        <option value="6000">$60.00</option>
        <option value="6500">$65.00</option>
        <option value="7000">$70.00</option>
        <option value="7500">$75.00</option>
        <option value="8000">$80.00</option>
        <option value="8500">$85.00</option>
        <option value="9000">$90.00</option>
        <option value="9500">$95.00</option>
        <option value="10000">$100.00</option>
</select>
```

Every time this  is changed I have some javascript that runs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#amount").change(function(){
      var amount = parseInt($("#amount option:selected").val());
      var amount = amount.toFixed(2);
      $(".amountShow").text('$'+amount);
   });
</script>
```

Now it almost works. Except for the `toFixed(2)` part of everything. Let's say we select 10.00. The value is 1000 and I am wanting to display 10.00. It instead displays like: 1000.00.

What more do I need to do? I converted the text to a integer and then fixed it two decimal places.

Comment: Try `var amount = (amount / 100).toFixed(2);`

Comment: Or you can just remove the extra zero's from the value.

Comment: [*toFixed*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-number.prototype.tofixed) is a built–in ECMAScript function, it is not jQuery.

Comment: Or you can just add decimal delimiters to the values, and use `parseFloat` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to divide by `100` the value of the option like : http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/14rh32ou/

```
$("#amount").change(function () {
    var amount = parseInt($("#amount option:selected").val()) / 100;
    var amount = amount.toFixed(2)
    $(".amountShow").text('$' + amount);

});
```